# Getting "Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined" from AngularJS $Filter

Tags: angularjs, filter

I am using AngularJS. I am using a filter to create a pagination for the table I am showing data in. The filter works fine when everything has loaded, but initially, it cannot read 'slice' of undefined. My guess is that it runs before it has some proper data to work with. My question is. Where should I put it?. for now it lives at the bottom of my controller file. should it be in a separate file? If so how do I use it?

Code

```
    app.filter('startFrom', function () {
    return function (input, start) {
        start = + parseInt(start);
        return input.slice(start);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize the variable at the beginning of the controller I think.

Or even better, you can check if the `input` exists before doing the slice. Like this:

```
app.filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
        if (!input || !input.length) { return; }
        start = +start;
        return input.slice(start);
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you sir!. Been sitting here for 5 hours working on this project and totally missed this solution. I think its time to hit the bed.